# que valor tiene el primer parámetro de getDirectory() en HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, api

Quiero saber que valor (internamente) tiene la variable "ruta" en la función **mostrar()** específicamente la linea *espacio.getDirectory(**ruta**, null, leer, errores);*, ya que en la función **crearsis()** se ha declarado vacia ("") y no se si toma algún valor en alguna otra parte del código o si continua vacía. Y que exactamente es lo que realiza la linea *espacio.getDirectory(**ruta**, null, leer, errores);* internamente.

```html
function comenzar(){
    zonadatos=document.getElementById("zonadatos");
    var boton=document.getElementById("boton");
    boton.addEventListener("click", crear, false);
    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(5*1024*1024, acceso);
}

function acceso(){
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, crearsis, errores);

}

function crearsis(sistema){

    espacio=sistema.root;
    ruta="";
    mostrar();
}

function crear(){
    var nombre_archivo=document.getElementById("entrada").value;
    if(nombre_archivo!=""){
        nombre_archivo=ruta + nombre_archivo;
       
        espacio.getFile(nombre_archivo, {create:true, exclusive:false}, mostrar, errores);
    }
}

function mostrar(entrada){
    document.getElementById("entrada").value="";
    zonadatos.innerHTML="";
    espacio.getDirectory(ruta, null, leer, errores);
}

function leer(directorio){
    lector=directorio.createReader();
    leer_todo();

}

function leer_todo(){
    lector.readEntries(function(archivos){
        if(archivos.length){
            listar(archivos);
        }
    }, errores);
}

function listar(archivos){
    for(var i=0; i<archivos.length;i++){
        if(archivos[i].isFile){
            zonadatos.innerHTML+=archivos[i].name+"<br>";
        }else if(archivos[i].isDirectory){
            zonadatos.innerHTML+="<spam class='directorio'>" + archivos[i].name + "</spam><br>";
        }
    }
}

function errores(e){
    alert(e.code);
}

window.addEventListener("load", comenzar, false);
```

Estoy haciendo un curso y no entiendo muy bien, agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar con este tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la funcion `getDirectory()` hace parte de un api para guardar archivos usando el navegador, esta es un api que permite usar tu web como un "almacenamiento" local para cada usuario en su navegador ( *los archivos que guardas no se guardan en el directorio de archivos del usuario como es habitual si no en el navegador*) las rutas usadas por esta api son:

```
//www.***.com/persistent/  PARA ARCHIVOS PERMANTES
//www.***.com/temporary/  PARA ARCHIVOS TEMPORALES
```

Respondiendo a tu pregunta entonces  `ruta = ""` hace referencia a la raiz osea `persistent/` o `temporary/`  según corresponda.

Un ejemplo de implementación seria

```
    var ruta =  "" //la declaro como global

    ...
    espacio.getFile(ruta+'foo.txt',...) // crear o busca  `temporary/foot.txt`
    ruta = "bar"
    espacio.getFile(ruta+'foo.txt',...) // crear  `temporary/bar/foot.txt`
    //la linea anterior puede dar error porque file solo crear archivos
    // y el directorio /bar aun no existe
    espacio.getDirectory(ruta,...) // crear la carpeta `temporary/bar/`
    espacio.getFile(ruta+'foo.txt',...) // crear  `temporary/bar/foot.txt`
```

Puedes leer un poco más en [blog de /www.jotform.com](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit/) 
y la documentación en  [Mozilla MDN API/FileSystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) .

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda comenta.

Comment: ahhh vale! y sabes cómo puedo crear un file dentro de un directorio? Gracias!

Comment: Actualmente  no conozco un API de Web que permita escribir archivos directamente sobre el "Disco" del usuario, tendrás que hacer que el usuario descargue un programa de escritorio para eso ya sea codificado en java, python , c#,  o programar con Electrón una alternativa para crear apps de escritorio usando javascriptm html y css